# Haskell Stack does not build postgresql-libpq on Nixos

Tags: haskell, haskell-stack, nixos

After adding *postgresql-libpq* to my project's cabal file, *stack build* fails with the following:

```
Configuring postgresql-libpq-0.9.1.1...
setup: The program 'pg_config' is required but it could not be found.
```

I'm on Nixos and *pg_config* is both installed and on my PATH:

```
$ whereis pg_config
pg_config: /nix/store/5bc6hzqkyw8dpi91sqznd3ik42mllwyz-system-path/bin/pg_config
```

I'm using stack 1.0.2, and it seems that it won't update even after *nixos-rebuild switch --upgrade* on the unstable channel. Is this a mistake on my side or is it something else?

Comment: I'm not familiar with the Stack+Nix integration, but does `stack exec whereis pg_config` find the `pg_config` location?

Comment: @MichaelSnoyman I get "Executable named whereis not found on path".. The printed path directories do not contain my system path, where most programs are to be found (including *whereis* and *pg_config*).

Comment: It sounds like you've enabled nix in your config but haven't specified the necessary packages. I'm not a nix user, so I can't advise further, but [this documentation](https://docs.haskellstack.org/en/stable/nix_integration/#the-nix-shell) seems to cover the topic.

Comment: I've tried adding some packages to the nix section withtou success, but it certainly makes sense that using things from PATH doesn't help with reproducible builds. I'll look into it further in the appropriate channels. Thank you for your attention.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I ran into this issue with stack on nixos, and got past it when the nix block of my `stack.yaml` had been changed to the following.

```
nix:
  pure: true
  enable: true
  packages: [ postgresql ]
```

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem, and reading the [docs](https://docs.haskellstack.org/en/stable/nix_integration/#the-nix-shell) linked by Michael Snoyman helped me. You need to add this to your stack.yaml:

```
nix:
  enable: true
  pure: false
```

I was building the package not owned by me, so instead of editing project-specific config I added those those lines to my *global* config: `~/.stack/config.yaml`. Alternatively, you can use command-line options:

```
stack --nix --no-nix-pure build
```

Alternatively to "non-pure" build, you should be able to specify all system dependencies in `nix-shell` to enforce reproducibility, but I didn't try it.

Comment: This is strange.. setting `pure: false` didn't help me at all.. in the end I put *postgresql* in the packages list to get it working..

Comment: @MarceloZabani I am having a similar problem as this question. To which packages list did you add 'postgresql' to get it working?

Comment: @mherzl sorry for not answering earlier. I guess you found out where, though!

Comment: No worries @MarceloZabani. Yep got it working as described in the answer!

Comment: `pure: false` is very important, if application you build requires access to environment. In my case application built with default stack `pure: true` couldn't access environment variable DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS, which is required by [fdo-notify](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/fdo-notify-0.3.1/docs/DBus-Notify.html#v:connectSession). Instead it worked fine by with `cabal build`. TR;DL: `pure: false` let me use `stack` again. Many thanks for the hint;-)